# I have a Samsung Galaxy S10e and I record videos in UHD 30 fps. How come there are "Extra" frames?

Tags: video, editing

When I am in post, for example Mocha, doing motion tracking - it really makes linear planar tracking more difficult with these random "extra" still frames once in a while. It happens without much of a pattern as far as I can tell. It'll be frame 20, 300, or whathave you. Once in a while, there will be two side to side identical frames.

Any way I can eliminate these simply? Is it a mismatch of settings?

Comment: Welcome! Is your phone recording with a variable frame rate or variable bit rate? A lot of software that isn't designed for consumers/phones has trouble dealing with either of those. You can use MediaInfo to check your source files and try transcoding to constant bit rate/constant framerate.

Comment: I figured that out Michael. My S10e apparently only records variable frame rates. I am using Handbrake to convert to constant FPS. But I am still finding duplicate frames.